# Android ADAL Active Directory Auth Library: Allow only Work accounts, not personal Microsoft accounts

Tags: android, adal

We noticed in the Office 365 login page, users are asked to enter work, school or **personal Microsoft accounts**. As an enterprise work account based app, we don’t want users to complete sign in with outlook.com or other personal Microsoft ids.

[image]

I’ve seen in iOS apps like Groups iOS using ADAL that take people to login page that allows only work or school account. Entering an outlook.com says its not supported.

Can we do this in Android maybe with a query param or similar? I couldn’t find this config in the Github readme

Answer (score 1):

Simply add queryParam

```
msafed=0
```

Use this in the

```
AuthenticationContext.acquireToken()
```

parameters